# Multiplying two sub-matrices in NumPy without copying the matrices

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrices `A` and `B` and I'm interested in multiplying a sub-matrix of `A` (defined by some of its rows) and a sub-matrix of `B` (defined by some of its columns) as shown in the example below:

```py
import numpy as np

# create two matrices
A = np.ones((5, 3))
B = np.ones((3, 5))

# define sub-matrices
rows_idx = [0, 2, 3]
cols_idx = [1, 2, 4]

# print sub-matrices
print(A[rows_idx])
print(B[:, cols_idx])
```

I'm aware that this can be achieved directly through

```py
A[rows_idx, :] @ B[:, cols_idx]
```

However, the latter comes with the drawback of making copies of the rows of `A` and columns of `B` since `rows_idx` and `cols_idx` are lists, as mentioned [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.copies.html#copies-and-views).
This is less efficient in terms of time and memory.

Also, I refrained from creating a Python function to perform the multiplication as Python loops are slow. Numpy array operations are much faster. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-numpy-is-faster-in-python/) are some timing comparisons.

Is there way to compute `A[rows_idx, :] @ B[:, cols_idx]` without copying?

Comment: Nope.  Making intermediate arrays is cost that we have to accept to take advantage of the compiled numpy building blocks.  `@` is implemented in super-fast library functions that know nothing about array indexing.  For optimal performance they need straight forward arrays.  And this being Python, the indexing is done before the results are passed to `matmul`.

Comment: Sometimes if the arrays are very large (multi-megabyte), and the indexing ends up selecting relatively small parts, it is time efficient to do the Python level iteration.  But don't focus on that kind of optimization until you know it's a problem.

Comment: By using `matmul` directly you get access to the `out` parameter so can write directly into a target array, which might save a copy.  Not sure if you care about this here